# Unable to execute git tf command

Tags: git, tfs, git-tf

I just setup git-tf, but I'm running into an issue.

Here's the error I'm receiving:

```
> git tf help
line 23: exec: cmd: not found
fatal: 'tf' appears to be a git command, but we were not
able to execute it. Maybe git-tf is broken?
```

Here is a screenshot of the command prompt:

[image: git-tf error]

I followed the instructions for installation that appear in the included `Git-TF_GettingStarted.html` file, but I can't seem to get this to work.  What have I done wrong?

**Edit**
I also have cygwin installed and on my PATH.  Maybe this is causing confusion for git-tf?  (Removing cygwin from PATH does nothing to help)

Comment: Fyi I posted this as a screenshot because SO doesn't like it when you use the word `help` in the post.

Comment: Putting the error in a code-block seems to work (although I'm not sure if editing is treated differently to posting a new question)

Comment: What is your PATH?  Does it contain %WINDIR%?

Comment: No, it contains (among other things) `C:\git-tf-1.0.0.20120809;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the `git-tf` sh script on Windows, where we assume that %WINDIR% is in your path when we should be providing a full path to `cmd.exe` when we try to launch it.

Until we've released a fix for this, you can do one of two things:

1. Add `%WINDIR%\system32` to your path.
2. Edit `git-tf` and change line 23.  Instead of simply `exec`'ing `cmd`, the appropriate line (in mingw32) should be:

   ```
   exec "$WINDIR/system32/cmd.exe" //C "$0.cmd" "$@"
   ```

Comment: I modified the line and it's now working.  Thanks for the quick fix!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the version of Cygwin I have installed or what but I just ran into this same problem and the above solution did not work. The problem was with the $0 substitution having a unix style path and cmd.exe choked on it.

In order to fix it, I changed this line:

```
exec $COMSPEC //C "$0.cmd" "$@"
```

to this:

```
exec $(cygpath $COMSPEC) /C $(cygpath --windows "$0.cmd") "$@"
```

That might only work for Cygwin. I never used MinGW32 and I'm not sure if its cygpath utility does exactly the same thing.

Comment: We've got an outstanding PR for a similar fix (maybe from you even?).  We'll have a fix for this in the next release of `git-tf`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "\" in %COMSPEC% will mess up with "git tf" under windows cmdline or mingw32

```
if [ "$PLATFORM" = "cygwin" ]; then
    COMSPEC_U=`cygpath -u "$COMSPEC"`
    GITTF_CMD=`cygpath -w "$0.cmd"`
    exec "$COMSPEC_U" /C "$GITTF_CMD" "$@"
elif [ "$PLATFORM" = "mingw32" ]; then
#   exec "$COMSPEC" //C git-tf.cmd "$@"
    exec "C:/WINDOWS/system32/cmd.exe" //C git-tf.cmd "$@"
fi
```